# How to access Elements in a Templates using TemplateRef in angular

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Suppose I have an HTML structure like this

```
<ng-template #template1>
    <div>
        element one
    </div>
    <div>
        element two
    </div>
    <div>
        element three
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

now, Inside this template, I have three elements, How can I access each element when I get the reference of it using TemplateRef. I tried using this

```
@ViewChild('template1', { static: false, read: TemplateRef }) template: QueryList<ElementRef>
```

but I am not getting individual elements, How can I achieve this

Comment: Refer to this stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kgw8lx

Comment: You can't get a reference to the elements in the template. You could access the elements once the template is rendered via DOM, but before that you can't access them via TemplateRef.

Comment: Generally if you're asking how to access elements in the template, you're doing something un-Angular. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @WillAlexander, i wanted to learn the workings of templateRef in depth, when asked about templateRef, people say a templateRef can contain many elements inside it, if that is the case then there should be a way to access individual element present inside the templateRef